# Projeto do Parse com faixas pretas

Tags: swift, xcode, parse

Estou utilizando o projeto do Parse.com na versão 7 do Xcode, porém, o app fica com uma faixa preta na parte superior e outra na parte inferior conforme mostrado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando a versão em swift do projeto. Alguém saberia me falar o que isso significa? Já efetuei algumas pesquisas mas não achei nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tive esse mesmo problema, porém em uma tela que eu mesmo criei, a causa dele é a resolução da sua "launch screen". Como é a primeira tela a ser mostrada no aplicativo, o IOS seta a resolução da tela do aparelho com a mesma da launch screen, ficando assim com essas faixas ao entrar em uma tela com resolução diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Vá no arquivo Images.xcassets, procure o item LaunchImage e tenha certeza de que todas as imagens para os aparelhos que irão rodar seu app esteja neste arquivo. Não coloque imagem para iPad se seu aplicativo não tiver versão para iPad.

Caso ainda assim não funcione, clique na raiz do seu projeto, selecione General e procure App Icons and Launch Images. Tenha certeza de que a sua LaunchImage esteja selecionada em Launch Image Source.

Boa sorte!